# Access to music folder on different devices

Tags: android

I have music download and player application, the problem is that I am getting massive ammount of null pointer exceptions every day because directory path is different on different devices.
How to resolve it?

Here is my path:

```
final String MEDIA_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/Music");
```

and here how i'm creating song list (getPlaylist):

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){
    File home = new File(MEDIA_PATH);

    if (home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter()).length > 0) {
        for (File file : home.listFiles(new FileExtensionFilter())) {
            HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();
            song.put("songTitle", file.getName().substring(0, (file.getName().length() - 4)));
            song.put("songPath", file.getPath());
            songsList.add(song);
        }
    }
    return songsList;
}
```

Stack trace from crash analytics service:

```
    Full Stack Trace:
java.lang.NullPointerException
music.download.justin.utils.SongReader.getPlayList(SongReader.java:22)
music.download.justin.Player.player(Player.java:164)
music.download.justin.Player.onViewCreated(Player.java:103)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:250)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:776)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:579)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:547)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:762)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:800)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5371)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Mostly affected devices:
Samsung (all models)
Kyocera
HTC

Comment: Have you seen this:  http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/150/storing-files-in-internal-external-storage#t=201608031018161454618 and Tried it.

Comment: You can get the music path directly from the environment, can't you? Maybe see @HtmlTosin 's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this was happening because of the device couldn't able to load the media path from SD card/External storage. you could either use Exception handling/throw some valid error message in else condition to avoid the crash or Exceptions.

Check the android version of those devices, if it exceeded to marshmallow, then you must to specify the permission at the code level.